# how to remove persistent outlets and actions

Tags: objective-c, xib, ibaction, iboutlet

I have an unused outlet and action that still show in the File's Owner Outlets and Received Action List.  I deleted the objects (tableView and button) and the associated code from the .m and .h files, but the unlinked outlet and actions still show in the list.  Can these be removed? Is it a problem?

I've tried creating a new set of objects, linking them and removing a couple of different ways (probably not exhaustive), but to no avail.

Comment: Sometimes I find Xcode doesn't update right away or not at all. Double check you've deleted them in the header files, and try doing a Clean. If that doesn't work, try deleting the derived data folder.

Comment: "Clean" and "delete derived data" is what I was looking for.  I recall seeing the derived data folder previously and I will dig around for the "Clean".  I will try those and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: No joy on "Product>>Clean" (shift-command K)...

Comment: No joy on deleting derived data either :(

Answer (score 2):

Did you click on the 'x' in these lists to remove the connection?  If not, do that.

[image: Delete Connection]

Comment: yes, the "X" was clicked... I had to create a new object and re-link it to verify.  I couldn't remember if I clicked the "x" before deleting the code.  As it is now, the "x" does not show because there is no object to link to it, however the action and outlets are still present (without the connection).

Answer (score 1):

Select the .xib file then Ctrl click, Open As.., Source Code.

Find and delete any xml blocks for that old outlet.

EDIT: Sorry I thought that would be easy to follow. Let me expand...

For example: If I had deleted a Button named btnPrevious from my view without clearing the outlet links first. I would have outlets listed but no way of clearing them from the view.

I would then open the viewcontroller's .xib file (by Ctrl click/Open As../Source Code) and search (Ctrl F) for any blocks containing the words "btnPrevious". Delete any code blocks found that relate to the deleted outlet. There should be a few of them in the .xib file.
Here is an example of a code block from the .xib file to be deleted. Delete the whole block  to  inclusive.

```
<object class'"IBActionInfo" key="btnPrevious_Click:">
    <string key="name">btnPrevious_Click:</string>
    (string key="candidateClassName">id</string>
</object>
```

Comment: that sounds reasonable... I had attempted that before I posted, but I realized very quickly that I had no idea how to recognize what I was looking for and that what I was doing wouldn't break something else.  An example might be nice.